# How to find objects in front of my player

Tags: unity, collision-detection, platformer, raycasting

I am trying to find an object that is in front of my player sprite using the following code

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,Vector2.right,EnemyLayer);
//EnemyLayer is the layer having enemy
if(hit!=null){
print (hit.collider.tag);

}
```

But this is printing "player",the tag of the object on which the script is attached.What am i doing wrong?
EDIT: Ok,I found out why it was printing player-because I had a big circular collider surrounding my player. Deactivating it gives me the following error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I have no clue what it means. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can't really help you debug your code. Step through it.

Answer (score 1):

With only the given information I would assume one of a few scenarios is happening here:

1. Something very mysterious because you provided very little information
2. Your player is on the enemy layer and subsequently the ray immediately hits the player
3. You are not setting up your EnemyLayer variable correctly.

To filter a Raycast based on layer you need to set up a layer mask. A layer mask is the result of bitshifting (>>) the layer numbers and combine multiple layer masks into a final layer mask using the binary OR operator (|).

```
int layer1 = 3;
int layer2 = 5;
int layermask1 = 1 << layer1;
int layermask2 = 1 << layer2;
int finalmask = layermask1 | layermask2; //variable to use as the Raycast() layermask parameter
```

Given your specific code, we are only working with one layer it looks like so your code might look something like this assuming you've set up the enemy layer on the first available custom layer which would be layer 8.

```
int enemyLayer = 8;            
int enemyMask = 1 << enemyLayer;            
//int layerMask = enemyMask; //No need for setting up a final mask because we only have one layer to check

RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, enemyMask);
```

**To comment on your edit:**

The above should help you resolve the issue with not needing to disable your player collider. The null reference exception is likely due to the fact that you aren't colliding anything. You need to actually check if `hit.collider` is null as hit will return information even if it doesn't hit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code is not correct:

```
if(hit!=null){
    print (hit.collider.tag);
}
```

Raycast will **ALWAYS** return not null object. And you **ALWAYS** need to check hit.collider for null. It can be found easy in manual:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html